# How to deploy job required library to all data nodes?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a mapreduce job which required around 300mb third-party libraries. In order to avoid the cost of copying libraries to data node when running the job. I wonder if there is a way/tool to that can pre-deploy these libraries to all data nodes before job start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy it to Hadoop's distributed cache. Pere Ferrera Bertran [explains this well](http://www.datasalt.com/2011/05/handling-dependencies-and-configuration-in-java-hadoop-projects-efficiently/)

Comment: My question is not clear enough. I actually want to deploy all jar files before the job started. If I use the distributed cache, the time of copying jars is still count in the job run time.

Comment: If you had had read the link you would have seen that it explains this point- if you use the distributed cache programmatically rather than using -libjars you can control when the files are deleted (Also he provides and additional option of copying the files to $HADOOP_HOME/lib which might work for you)